# marquee effect in uitableviewcells textlabel.text

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is there a way to accomplish something like the html Marquee effect for a uitableviewcells textlabel.text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to implement it yourself using a NSTimer. You would cycle trough the characters of your `textLabel.text` by taking one from the front and appending it to the back. In order to do this easily you could use a `NSMutableString` that you would manipulate using `substringWithRange:` `deleteCharactersInRange:` and `appendString`, and then set as `textLabel.text` after each character manipulation:

```
- (void)fireTimer
{
  NSMutableString *mutableText = [NSMutableString stringWithString: textLabel.text];
  //Takes the first character and saves it into a string
  NSString *firstCharText = [mutableText substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
  //Removes the first character
  [mutableText deleteCharactersInRange: NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
  //Adds the first character string to the initial string
  [mutableText appendString: firstCharText];

  textLabel.text = mutableText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Worked like a charme.

Comment: Not very smooth, but results vs. lines of code is just perfect!

Comment: This is like the first hit when i searched so I figured i would update this solution: https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel is really easy to use and does all the work. Very smooth. If using in a table view, make sure to read my comments here: https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel/issues/25

Comment: @LEO thank you so much for the marquee label link :)